# Jquery function does not update all the column

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new programming in Jquery and i have a problem on my webpage when the jquery function is ejected.

This is my webpage if you want to do any test [www.nutrinet.hol.es/index6.php](http://www.nutrinet.hol.es/index6.php)

When any product is selected, the column 'Unidad Maxima' and 'Unidad minima' change.

But when the other product is selected (3th for example), only their row mentioned changes and the next rows change, the other rows (2th and 1th) still unupdated.

This is my jquery function. Val3 = 'Unidades elegidas' column fields.

```
$(document).ready(function () {



   $(".txtMult input").keyup(multInputs);

   function multInputs() {

       var mult = 0;
       var sum = 0;
       var cantidadfinal = 0;
       var preciofinal =0;
       var cantidadesminimas = 0;

               var cantidadesmaximas = 0;


       // for each row:
       $("tr.txtMult").each(function () {


           // get the values from this row:
           var $val1 = $('.val1', this).val();
           var $val2 = $('.val2', this).val();
           var $val3 = $('.val3', this).val();
           var $val4 = $('.val4', this).val();



           var $total = ($val1 * 1) * ($val2 * 1)
           var $cantidadestotales = ($val3 * 1) * ($val2 * 1)
           var $preciostotales = ($val4 * 1) * ($val2 * 1)         


           mult += $total;

           cantidadfinal += $cantidadestotales;

           preciofinal += $preciostotales;

            sum += parseFloat($val2);

            cantidadesminimas = (8260 - cantidadfinal) / $val3

            cantidadesmaximas =  (12390 - cantidadfinal) / $val3 


             $('.val5',this).html(cantidadesminimas.toFixed(0));

              $('.val6',this).html(cantidadesmaximas.toFixed(0));



       });

       $("#precio").html(preciofinal.toFixed(0));
      $("#cantidadelegida").html(cantidadfinal.toFixed(0));
       $("#sum").html(sum.toFixed(0));
       $("#grandTotal").html(mult.toFixed(0));
        $("#cantidadmin").html(8260-cantidadfinal.toFixed(0));
        $("#cantidadmax").html(12390-cantidadfinal.toFixed(0));
         $("#kcaltotal").html(14000-mult.toFixed(0));

   }
```

});

Any comment will be very apreciated.Thanks!

Comment: is it the expected behaviour that more than one row is updated when an input is changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, got it. The thing is that the variables `cantidadesminimas` and `cantidadesmaximas` depend on the value of `cantidadfinal` and we don't know the valid value of `cantidadfinal` until we've gone through **all** the rows. This leads to the error: if row `x` comes after row `y` its `cantidadfinal`doesn't take into account the values of row `y` and therefore remains unmodified. The quickest solution is to loop twice: firstly to calculate `cantidadfinal` and the other loop to set the correct values in `.val5` and `.val6`.

```
$(".txtMult input").keyup(multInputs);
function multInputs() {
    var mult = 0;
    var sum = 0;
    var cantidadfinal = 0;
    var preciofinal = 0;
    var cantidadesminimas = 0;
    var cantidadesmaximas = 0;

    // for each row:
    $("tr.txtMult").each(function () {
        // get the values from this row:
        var $val1 = $('.val1', this).val();
        var $val2 = $('.val2', this).val();
        var $val3 = $('.val3', this).val();
        var $val4 = $('.val4', this).val();

        var $total = ($val1 * 1) * ($val2 * 1);
        var $cantidadestotales = ($val3 * 1) * ($val2 * 1);
        var $preciostotales = ($val4 * 1) * ($val2 * 1);

        mult += $total;
        cantidadfinal += $cantidadestotales;
        preciofinal += $preciostotales;
        sum += parseFloat($val2);
    });

    // Now we have the correct cantidadfinal and can update the values properly
    $("tr.txtMult").each(function () {
        var $val3 = $('.val3', this).val();
        cantidadesminimas = (8260 - cantidadfinal) / $val3;
        cantidadesmaximas = (12390 - cantidadfinal) / $val3;

        $('.val5', this).html(cantidadesminimas.toFixed(0));
        $('.val6', this).html(cantidadesmaximas.toFixed(0));
    });

    $("#precio").html(preciofinal.toFixed(0));
    $("#cantidadelegida").html(cantidadfinal.toFixed(0));
    $("#sum").html(sum.toFixed(0));
    $("#grandTotal").html(mult.toFixed(0));
    $("#cantidadmin").html(8260 - cantidadfinal.toFixed(0));
    $("#cantidadmax").html(12390 - cantidadfinal.toFixed(0));
    $("#kcaltotal").html(14000 - mult.toFixed(0));

}
```

For the next time I recommend you use a very nice javascript plugin called knockout, it does this kind of things really nice and easy.

You can check the result in this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tf28vap5/5/)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much acontell for help me but i need to update all the fields because the user needs to see the minimum of each product in relation with the 'Cantidad minima que queda' value that changes constantly by choising the quantity of the products. That's the reason to update all the fields but i dont know why if i modify  the quantity of the 2th product five times for example, the 1th field stills unupdated when the others are updated without any problem.

Comment: @user3436868 thanks for the clarification, my mistake, I misunderstood the problem. I'll have a look and tell you something if I come up with a solution, cheers!

Comment: Sorry for my bad explanation of my problem, thank you very much. I'll try to solve this also. Have a nice day!

Comment: Yeah! you have solved the problem!. Thank you very much! genius! :)

Comment: @user3436868 thanks :) glad to help! please, accept the answer if everything's ok